# IllegalArguementException in clojure when trying to cons and reduce

Tags: clojure

i'm getting the error `IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:487)` when executing the following code:

```
(defn phrase-length [phr]
    (loop [n 0 b () s ()]
      (if (= n (count phr))
        (concat #(reduce + b) #(reduce + s))
        (recur (inc n)
               (cons (nth (nth (nth phr n) 1) 0) b)
               (cons (nth (nth (nth phr n) 1) 1) s)))))
```

The error is occurring in the line of the `concat`.  It must be something with trying to reduce while also concatting.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to concat `#(reduce + b)` and `#(reduce + s)`. That doesn't work, `#(reduce + b)` expands to `(fn* [] (clojure.core/reduce clojure.core/+ your-namespace/b))`. You can't concat functions. Maybe you meant `(reduce + b)` but that doesn't make any sense either because the result of that is a number, and you can't concat numbers either. Maybe you meant 
`[(reduce + b) (reduce + s)]` or `(map + b s)` or `(+ (reduce + b) (reduce + s))` but I can't do more than blindly guess here without knowing what you're actually trying to achieve.

These lines:

```
           (cons (nth (nth (nth phr n) 1) 0) b)
           (cons (nth (nth (nth phr n) 1) 1) s)
```

are weird too. Is phr a seq of seqs of seqs of longs?

Is your collection of this form `[[[0 0 ,,,] [0 1 ,,,] ,,,] ,,,]` (you'd cons 0 to b and 1 to s here)? If so, you should probably write functions for accessing those values, as it is it's a chore to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

[nth](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/nth) returns a value.

When you do `(cons (nth (nth (nth phr n) 1) 0) b)`, after the evaluation of the `(nth phr n)` you will apply the next `nth` in a value, not in a Seq.

Testing your code with something like `(phrase-length "123")` will raise the error that you are getting.